Hitting a target moving at light speed
Initially a target and a person with a laser aiming at the target were 1 meter apart.
Somehow the target was accelerated to light speed in an instant and the laser was switched on.
(Considering the effects of relativity)
Will the photons from the laser hit the target in the target's frame? Also will the photons from the laser hit the target in the frame of reference of the person holding the laser?

Somehow the target was accelerated to light speed. Not physically possible.

Indeed, in saying "to light speed in an instant" there's a two impossible situations. Every process takes time, and not only that,- it can only take such $t_{min}$ which is bounded by system's energy input supply, for example- you can't speed-up a rocket faster than it's given propellant/engine system effectivity can offer. Lastly, there's no system in the world and even it can't be created even theoretically which could speed-up a physical body to the light speed $c$, because it will require infinite amount of supply energy and/or infinite amount of time, which obviously can't be.

@AgniusVasiliauskas Barring warp drives. But those can’t exist anyways due to negative energy requirements… I’m nit-picking the “even theoretically part” mostly. With appropriate modifications to the metric you can theoretically get to whatever speed you want; you just couldn’t do that in real life.

What do the laws of physics say will happen if we do what the laws of physics say we cannot do? The laws of physics don't say!

@SolomonSlow You should get that on a t-shirt. Truly well said.

@controlgroup Yeah, it's a very interesting theoretical research direction. I even read somewhere that it's proven that it's possible to eliminate negative energy requirement for such Alcubierre like drives, but normal matter consumption for such "engines" would be still abnormal,- don't recall exact numbers,- but it's on the order of "just" couple of $M_{\odot}$ masses per hour or something like that. So yeah, if you want to screw-up everything in a galaxy along the way to the Alpha Centauri,- why not ? :-D

@controlgroup Personally for me,- destination crash is the most fun part of such travel :-)

That is usually the issue with such devices… if only the drive didn’t require building a massive one-way wall around your ship that absorbs huge amounts of interstellar particles ;)

If the target has mass, it can't be accelerated to the speed of light, although it can be accelerated as close as the speed of light as we want - at least in a though experiment.
In the frame of reference of the target the speed of light is constant - as in any other frame of reference. Therefore, the target will observe the laser hitting them in a finite time (and a very short one).
An external observer will see the laser hitting the target in a longer time. Since we can make the target speed arbitrarily close to the speed of light, we can make the time to hit arbitrarily large.
If the target were to achieve speed of light, then it would have no mass and it would experience no time (all instants would be the same). In fact, the target would be just another light pulse, just like the laser. Then, it's debatable whether the target could meaningfully be said to observe anything, but an external observer would observe the laser never hitting the target, just as a light pulse can never catch another one.
